# Populating ComboBox with unique features in selected attribute field using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I am creating a plugin in QGIS where I want to read a Vector layer --> Select attribute column --> list unique values within the chosen attribute column in the selected attribute from the column.

I have been successful with the two first steps, but not with the third.

This is the code used so far, but I cannot get further than this.

```
self.layerComboManagerPoint = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self.dlg.comboBoxVector)
self.layerComboManagerPoint.setCurrentIndex(-1)
self.layerComboManagerPoint.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)
self.layerComboManagerPoint.setFixedWidth(175)

self.layerComboManagerPointField = QgsFieldComboBox(self.dlg.comboBoxField)
self.layerComboManagerPointField.setFilters(QgsFieldProxyModel.AllTypes) 
self.layerComboManagerPoint.layerChanged.connect(self.layerComboManagerPointField.setLayer)
```

I have tried googling, but I might just not have a reasonable word to google on.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the highlighted lines to your script:

```
self.layerComboManagerPoint = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self.dlg.comboBoxVector)
self.layerComboManagerPoint.setCurrentIndex(-1)
self.layerComboManagerPoint.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)
self.layerComboManagerPoint.setFixedWidth(175)

self.layerComboManagerPointField = QgsFieldComboBox(self.dlg.comboBoxField)
self.layerComboManagerPointField.setFilters(QgsFieldProxyModel.AllTypes) 
self.layerComboManagerPoint.layerChanged.connect(self.layerComboManagerPointField.setLayer)


################## ADD THESE LINES #########################
def field_changed(field):
    # get current layer
    layer = self.layerComboManagerPoint.currentLayer()
    # get index of the field
    i = layer.fields().indexOf(field)
    # get unique values
    unique_values = layer.uniqueValues(i)    
    # remove all values from comboBoxAttribute
    self.dlg.comboBoxAttribute.clear()    
    # add unique values
    self.dlg.comboBoxAttribute.addItems(unique_values)    

self.layerComboManagerPointField.fieldChanged.connect(field_changed)    
#############################################################
```

Comment: OK, it works fine, however, I also now understand that I need to be able to read other types than 'string'.

I tried 
`self.dlg.comboBoxAttributesetFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.AllTypes)`
But with no luck. Do you have any solution to this too?